How to remove "3D Objects" and other folders from This PC and Navigation Pane - Current User, Windows 10
I have seen many methods in Windows 10 for removing the 3D Objects, Documents, Desktop, Downloads, Music, Pictures, and Video folders from "This PC" and the "Navigation Pane" using the Registry but all of them require admin rights or at least the ability to remove keys from HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE.
Is there a way to remove these special folders for the current user only (HKEY_CURRENT_USER)?
Example for local machine:
[-HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MyComputer\NameSpace\{0DB7E03F-FC29-4DC6-9020-FF41B59E513A}]
[-HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MyComputer\NameSpace\{0DB7E03F-FC29-4DC6-9020-FF41B59E513A}]

I was able to remove them from the "This PC" folder view itself following this guide. However, they are still in my Navigation Pane.
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\HideMyComputerIcons]
"{0DB7E03F-FC29-4DC6-9020-FF41B59E513A}"=dword:00000001
"{d3162b92-9365-467a-956b-92703aca08af}"=dword:00000001
"{24ad3ad4-a569-4530-98e1-ab02f9417aa8}"=dword:00000001
"{3dfdf296-dbec-4fb4-81d1-6a3438bcf4de}"=dword:00000001
"{f86fa3ab-70d2-4fc7-9c99-fcbf05467f3a}"=dword:00000001
"{088e3905-0323-4b02-9826-5d99428e115f}"=dword:00000001
"{B4BFCC3A-DB2C-424C-B029-7FE99A87C641}"=dword:00000001

Special folders still in explorer Navigation Pane:

